# How to add my logo for the first 30 seconds in a video with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to add my logo for the first 30 seconds in a video with ffmpeg. I have a video called `d1.mp4` and a logo called `logo.png`.

When the video starts, the watermark should be at the top left or top right corner of the video and disappear after 30 seconds.

Can you please show me how to add it?

Comment: my video name is d1.mp4 and my logo name is logo.png ,thank you..

Comment: Then what does `ffmpeg -i d1.mp4 -i logo.png` show? Please just enter that command and show us what the output is. When asking questions about `ffmpeg`, you should always include as many details as possible about what video/audio material you have, what you already tried, and the full command line output of everything you have tried.

Comment: here's what i get on my cmd screen .  http://pastebin.com/bPCnhXh2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -framerate 30000/1001 -loop 1 -i logo.png -filter_complex
  "[1:v] fade=out:st=30:d=1:alpha=1 [ov]; [0:v][ov] overlay=10:10 [v]" -map "[v]"
  -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest out.mp4
```

This assumes that the logo is a single still image with an alpha channel and you want to overlay it over a video with a frame rate of 30000/1001 (NTSC rate).  Change the `-framerate` to match your input video if it is different.  If your logo is a video then omit `-framerate 30000/1001 -loop 1`.  If the logo does not have an alpha channel, add one by inserting e.g. `format=yuva420p,` immediately before `fade`.

This will display the logo at x,y position 10,10 for 30 seconds followed by a 1 second fade out.

Comment: Very Interesting! Could you explain why the `framerate` and `loop` are required in this case and not  for a simple overlay without fade filter?

Comment: Thank you very much mark40  but when i write this code, cmd screen doesn't stop.. I dont know why but it didnt work for me..

Comment: Hi LordNeckbeard,

Here's a screenshot.. http://u1312.hizliresim.com/1j/4/v5ny8.png ..

Comment: @iwocan Screenshots are not preferred over actual text. They are not searchable and do not show the complete output. If you use `@` before someone's name then they will be notified of your reply.

Comment: I can't copy anything on cmd screen that's why i sent you a screenshot.I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @iwocan I believe you can copy stuff out of the windows prompt. I assumed you would search how to do it, but look at [Copy To the Clipboard From the Windows Command Prompt](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/).

Comment: @iwocan: Sorry, add `-shortest` (or `-t` and the desired duration) before the output file name.  Otherwise the png will be looped forever.

Comment: @Rajib: The reason for the `-framerate` and `-loop` for a still image is so that the fade out will work.  If there is only a single frame then it has no way to fade out over a 1 second interval.  Ideally it should be the same frame rate as the video so that the fade will be as smooth as possible.

Comment: @mark4o Thank you very much! :) It works perfect! :)

Comment: I had no idea you could have two inputs!

Answer (score 20):

### Using [`overlay` video filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) to add a logo to a video:

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay" \
-codec:a copy out.mp4
```

To understand this command you need to know what a [stream specifier](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1) is and reading the [Introduction to FFmpeg Filtering](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) will help. `[0:v]` refers to the video stream(s) of first input (`video.mp4`), and `[1:v]` refers to the video stream of the second input (`logo.mp4`). This is how you can tell `overlay` what inputs to use. You can omit `[0:v][1:v]`, and `overlay` will still work, but it is recommended to be explicit and not rely on possibly unknown defaults.

By default the logo will be placed in the upper left.

Using `-codec:a copy` will [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio. This simply re-muxes the audio instead of re-encoding it. Think of it as a "copy and paste" of the audio.

### Moving the logo

This example will move the logo 10 pixels to the right, and 10 pixels down:
[image]

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10" \
-codec:a copy out.mp4
```

This example will move the logo 10 pixels from the right side and 10 pixels down:

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10" -codec:a copy out.mp4
```

`main_w` refers to the width of the "main" input (the background or `[0:v]`), and `overlay_w` refers to the width of the "overlay" input (the logo or `[1:v]`). So, in the example, this can be translated to `overlay=320-90-10:10` or `overlay=220:10`.

### Timing the overlay

Some filters can handle [timeline editing](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) which allows you to use [arithmetic expressions](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation) to determine when a filter should be applied. Refer to `ffmpeg -filters` to see which filters support timeline editing.

This example will show the logo until 30 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10:enable=between(t\,0\,30)" -codec:a copy out.mp4
```

If you want to fade the logo refer to [mark4o's answer](https://superuser.com/a/683696/110524).

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I apologize for my broken English again.This command works perfect! :)

Comment: finally something understandable! what should i use to make it appear at the beginning than at the end?

Comment: I meant to appear at the beginning AND at the end? Two times. i have tried enable=between(t\,0\,30):enable=between(t\,50\,60) , but the only last timeline is in effect

Comment: @cikatomo `enable=not(between'(t,30,50)')`. This will show the overlay at all times but not at 30-60 seconds duration.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Despite your warning to not use `overlay` all by itself, I did, because the default position of top left was what I wanted. (So in the end my flags were simply `filter_complex overlay`.)

Comment: I think it should be accepted answer.