# How to add a png logo to mp4 video with ffmpeg which can be resize dynamically and cover the whole video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I want to show a logoon a video when the video starts. I already found this command :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -framerate 30000/1001 \
-loop 1 -i test.png -filter_complex "[1:v] fade=out:st=30:d=1:alpha=1 [ov];\
 [0:v][ov] overlay=10:10 [v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 \
-c:a copy -shortest Bigout.mp4
```

from
[How to add my logo for the first 30 seconds in a video with ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/questions/683643/how-to-add-my-logo-for-the-first-30-seconds-in-a-video-with-ffmpeg)

But the problem is my video's widths/heights are different and each time I add a logo, it does not cover the whole video. What should I do if I want to set the logo width/height to the  width/height of the video ?

**UPDATE**
After @Behroozfar Answer, I tried to use scale2ref, with the command below:

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -framerate 30000/1001 -loop 1 -i biglogo.png -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw/1:-1[ovrl][0v]; [0v][ovrl]overlay=0:0[v]" -map "[v] ; [1:v] fade=out:st=2:d=1:alpha=1 [ov]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest Bigout.mp4

but the question is , I can't show the logo just for one second. It exists during the whole video play.

Answer (score 2):

Use `scale2ref` filter

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -framerate 30000/1001 \
-loop 1 -i test.png -filter_complex "[1:v]fade=out:st=30:d=1:alpha=1[ov]; \
[ov][0:v]scale2ref[logo][video]; \
[video][logo]overlay=10:10[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 \
-c:a copy -shortest Bigout.mp4`

Comment: To the OP, note that this will distort the logo if its aspect ratio and the video's aspect is different.

Comment: @Mulvya Actually i want to show logo for the first second of the video which cover the whole video frame, and then have the small logo for example in the left corner. I guess I should use two ffmepeg commands for this. One for adding the intro logo and then add the small logo to the video was made before.

Answer (score 0):

To show the full-sized logo for one second and then a small-sized logo afterwards, use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -framerate 30000/1001 -loop 1 -i test.png
       -filter_complex
         "[1]fade=out:st=1:d=0.9:alpha=1,trim=0:2[f]; \
          [1]fade=st=2:d=0.5:alpha=1,trim=0:3[s]; \
          [f][0]scale2ref[fs][video];[s][fs]scale2ref=iw/8:-1[ss][fo];
          [video][fo]overlay=eof_action=pass[v0]; \
          [v0][ss]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5[v]" \
       -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy Bigout.mp4
```

Comment: thank you man. I run the command and it said there no f! it seems [of] in your command should have been [f]. and run it again and I dont see any logo in my video. It seems nothing happened to the video

Comment: sorry, [fo] in your command should have been [f].

Comment: Made corrections.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine for the first part. But there is not small logo on the for the  second part

Comment: unfortunately your command doesn't work for the second part... and make the video stop at the last two seconds before finish. 
By the way it may seems a little bit stupid, but I decided to run two commands. first put the intro logo at the beginning and then add the small logo. But when I run your command for the first part, video stops two seconds before finish.

Comment: Although I can hear the sound of the video, but it stops at the last two seconds

Comment: Actually by running the updated command, ffmpeg stop working after 27 KB. I mean log file is sth like this :

Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale2ref:ref
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> scale2ref:default
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   60 fps=0.3 q=29.0 size=      27kB time=00:00:01.99 bitrate= 110.6kbits/s speed=0.0102x


and it took 80% of my memory  !

Comment: The only thing that happened with the last command update, was stopping at two seconds before finish and no logo at all !

Comment: truly Sorry , my mistake.I was copying wring file to be sent to output. It works perfectly. Thank you I really appreciate it.but I dont know how to mark your command as the answer